# How can I set string values in a static mut array/vec?

Tags: rust

I have a symbol table that I want to be static because it is accessed in a lot of circumstances where I don't have a good way to pass the value in. It is a struct and a table that looks like:

```rust
struct Symbol {
   string: &'static str,
   other_values: ...,
}
const NO_SYMBOL = Symbol{ string: "", other...};
static mut symbol_table : [Symbol;100] = [NO_SYMBOL;100];
```

How do I update the string field? It has to be static, because it's in a static array, but I want to generate values (among other things, by reading from a file), so how can I make a String static so I can store it in an element of the array?

Comment: `&'static str` is a string either baked in the binary or leaked. Are you sure you really need this and not `String`/`Box<str>`?

Comment: Alternatively, a `Cow<'static, str>` would allos mixing static strings created at compile time and dynamic strings allocated at runtime.

Comment: Either way using `lazy_static!` with proper synchronisation would probably be a better idea than a bare static mut`, those are gnarly.

Comment: Do you need to update the strings only once or multiple times?

Comment: I am OK with leaking the strings. I only need to update each string once, but new ones will be slowly added over the life of the program (which could be days), and once added they will **very** rarely stop being used (and I can manually discard them in those rare cases). I don't need Cow, I don't think. I'd be perfectly fine with having copies of the strings as there will be very few baked in the binary. String or Box<str> sounds OK, but how can I initialize it? I *could* use unsafe uninitialized data, as I could initialize values before I access them, but I'd prefer to keep it cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, depending on what you think is best.
Use a `Vec`:

```rust
static mut symbol_table_1:Vec<Symbol> = Vec:new(); //doesn't actually allocate so is a const fn
```

or use an option and `replace` the none values:

```rust
static mut symbol_table_2:[Option<Symbol>;100] = [None;100];

unsafe{
    symbol_table_2[0].replace(Some(value));
}
```

A `&'static str` can be obtained by using `String::into_boxed_str` and `Box::leak`.
However, I would highly encourage you to use `lazy_static` and an `RwLock`, which enables many readers or one writer to maintain a lock on the `static` and prevent data races.

```rust
lazy_static!{
    static ref symbol_table_3:Rwlock<Vec<Symbol>> = RwLock::new(Vec::new());
}
```

[Full playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6dcf4561fd10120542dc47c3aa43f0c6)

Comment: `Box::leak(s.into_boxed_str())` works great, and I was leaning toward a Vec and RwLock, so I've done that. My question now is in the rare cases where I actually am deleting one of the strings, I could recover that space if I could turn the `&'static str` back into a `String` that I could then drop. As I've said, not a huge deal if it's impossible, but it would be nice and clean.

Comment: @DaveMason you can recover the memory by using the `box::from_raw` method, but be very sure that the `str` is not in use anywhere if you do that.

Comment: Thanks @Aiden4 - is that safe regardless of whether the original str came from a String or Cow or literal? Ahh... I'm guessing the `into_boxed_str` makes it something that can be safely brought back with `from_raw`.

Comment: @DaveMason Don't deallocate a string literal that way-  only deallocate `&str`'s that are not in use anywhere and were heap-allocated either in a box or a string or similar. The Cow should be fine if you do `to_owned` and leak the resulting string.